# Downgrading or installing earlier version of a package with pip

Tags: pip

I have a version of a package installed (e.g. transformers 3.4.0) I want to install an earlier one.
I install with:

```
pip install transformers==3.1.0
```

When checking installed versions with

```
pip freeze
```

I see the version did not change.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Although not intuitive, `--upgrade` means to ignore the exact version and ignore the current one if not the same. So, you need to "upgrade" to the earlier version for example:

```
pip install --upgrade transformers==3.1.0
```

Answer (score 5):

upgrade can be used for both downgrades or upgrades.

```
pip install --upgrade transformers==3.1.0
```

If you want to play it safe, you can

```
pip uninstall transformers
pip install --upgrade transformers==3.1.0
```

upgrade works with -t --target parameter as well.

```
pip install --target lib --upgrade transformers==3.1.0
```