# API in Django with Tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have created an API in latest version of Django using latest version of Tastypie. When I run the server of Django I get this error:

> cant import "datetime_safe" from "django.utils"

I already have tried reinstalling the tastypie.

Answer (score 0):

The `datetime_safe` module Tastypie is trying to access [does not exist from version 5.0 of Django onwards](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-5-0#:%7E:text=The%20undocumented%20django.utils.datetime_safe%20module%20will%20be%20removed.). This is because [Tastypie requires Django version 4.2](https://pypi.org/project/django-tastypie/) and does not support Django 5.* which you seem to have installed.

**You need to run this in the command line to downgrade Django to v4.2.** ([source: this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65085962/downgrading-or-installing-earlier-version-of-a-package-with-pip))

```bash
python -m pip install --upgrade Django==4.2.8
```

I hope this is helpful - please let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install latest version of django-tastyepie from git repository

```
pip install git+https://github.com/django-tastypie/django-tastypie.git
```